# Вызов диалога выбора файла из JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, файлы

Как правильно вызывать диалог выбора файла программно из *JavaScript*? На данный момент создаю элемент `input[type="file"]` и вызываю его метод `click`:

```
var inputFile = document.createElement('input');
inputFile.setAttribute('type', 'file');
inputFile.click();
```

Comment: И в чём вопрос то?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, вопрос в том есть ли другие способы вызвать диалог выбора файла.